# Making border of image red on hover

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to making the border of the an image to be red when on hover, but it's not working for some reason. What am I doing wrong?

```css
img: hover {
border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<img src = 'http://www.keenthemes.com/preview/metronic/theme/assets/global/plugins/jcrop/demos/demo_files/image1.jpg'>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove the space after the colon. It works in Chrome and IE11, at least.

```css
img { border: 1px solid white; } 
img:hover {
border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<img src = 'http://www.keenthemes.com/preview/metronic/theme/assets/global/plugins/jcrop/demos/demo_files/image1.jpg'>
```

**EDIT:**  As mentioned in another answer, you may want to add a white border around the image so it won't shift when you hover over it.  I have incorporated that in the code snippet above.

Comment: Apparently, that's not always true :)

Comment: @jessica Well, this is CSS not HTML.

Answer (score 2):

Cant comment, but we are talking CSS here, not HTML.

Add in a border for default to fix jumpy image. U could do

```
img { border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0); }
```